# Convert conv2d into tf.nn.separable_conv2d running into memory error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently trying to make my network a little bit faster by using separable convolutions instead of regular ones. One remark dont get confused by the additional code snippets. They are put there to emphesise the problem. My guess is I build the depthwise and pointwise conv the wrong way but I have no clue how I can use it otherwise. THanks in advance!

I used the code below with my regular convolutions as an input I give a (1,800,800,3) input and use a 3x3 kernel and 32 filters. Both methods have the same syntax

```
def conv(input, kernel_size, filters, stride, is_training, batchnorm=True, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="conv"):
```

afterwards I define my variables w and b and batch norm.

```
with tf.variable_scope(name):
    weights = tf.get_variable('weights',
                              shape=[kernel_size, kernel_size, input.get_shape()[3], filters],
                              initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
                              )
    biases = tf.get_variable('biases',
                             shape=[filters],
                             initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0)
                             )
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input, weights, strides=[1, stride, stride, 1], padding='SAME')
    output = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)

    if batchnorm:
        output = tf.layers.batch_normalization(output, training=is_training, center=True, scale=False)

    if activation is not None:
        output = activation(output)
    return output
```

Until here everything works as expected and when I run my code i can train my network.

Now I tried to derive a separate convolution using the tf.nn.separable_conv2d

Therefore I used

```
with tf.variable_scope(name):
        weights = tf.get_variable('weights',
                                  shape=[kernel_size, kernel_size, input.get_shape()[3], filters],
                                  initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())

        pointwise_filter = tf.get_variable("pointwise_filter",shape = [1,1,input.get_shape()[3]*filters, filters],
                                    initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())

        biases = tf.get_variable('biases',
                                 shape=[filters],
                                 initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0)
                                 )
        conv = tf.nn.separable_conv2d(input, weights, pointwise_filter, strides=[1, stride, stride, 1], padding='SAME')
        output = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)

        if batchnorm:
            output = tf.layers.batch_normalization(output, training=is_training, center=True, scale=False)

        if activation is not None:
            output = activation(output)
        return output
```

The network is building fine and then I run into memory issues with my Gtx1080ti.

[image]